# doT.js: chained if-else if in dot.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dot.js

I was trying `doT.js` template engine.How to do nested if-else if in `dot.js` like

```
if()
 .....
else if
 .....
else if
 .....
else
 .....
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
{{? it.name }}
<div>Oh, I love your name, {{=it.name}}!</div>
{{?? it.age === 0}}
<div>Guess nobody named you yet!</div>
{{?? it.age > 20}}
<div>You're old!</div>
{{??}}
You are {{=it.age}} and still don't have a name?
{{?}}
```

The above gets compiled to:

```
function anonymous(it /**/) 
{ 
    var out='';

    if(it.name)
    {
        out+='<div>Oh, I love your name, '+(it.name)+'!</div>';
    }
    else if(it.age === 0)
    {
        out+='<div>Guess nobody named you yet!</div>';
    }
    else if(it.age > 20)
    {
        out+='<div>You\'re old!</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        out+='You are '+(it.age)+' and still don\'t have a name?';
    }
    return out; 
}
```

Essentially, just keep adding `{{?? condition}}` until you get to `{{?}}` (the end of the block).

Comment: Seems right, but the relationship of the properties in all of those conditionals can be confusing. You may want to edit so that you're just checking various possibilities of a single property.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```js
<!-- CONDITIONAL !-->
<!-- if -->
<div>
    {{? it[0].firstName }}
    {{=it[0].firstName }}
    {{?}}
</div>

<!-- if / else if / else -->
<div>
    <!-- if -->
    {{? it[0].lastName }}
    <span>First name is set</span>

    <!-- else if -->
    {{?? it[0].zip}}
    <span>You don't have a last name</span>

    <!-- else if -->
    {{?? it[0].firstName}}
    <span>Your firstName is: {{=it[0].firstName}}</span>

    <!-- else if end -->
    {{??}}
                         
    <!-- else -->
    <span>You didn't set your name</span>
                         
    <!-- if end -->
    {{?}}
</div>
```

Comment: this here is wrong:
<img src="{{=(user.absolutePath=='')?'img/user-shape.png':user.absolutePath;}}">

Answer (score 0):

this image tag is incorrect:

```html
 
<img src="{{=(user.absolutePath=='')?'img/user-shape.png':user.absolutePath;}}">
```

this is correct:

```js
            {{~it.userCollection[0].attributes.admin :user:index}}
                <div class="team-content-user">
                <!-- if not null-->
                {{?user.absolutePath}}
                    <img src="{{=user.absolutePath}}">
                    <!-- if not (not null) -->
                    {{??!user.absolutePath}}
                    <img src="img/user-shape.png">
                    {{??}}
                {{?}}
                {{=user.email}}</br>

                </div>
            {{~}}
```

Comment: if possible, please indicate why the excerpt cited is incorrect